# Understand how to change the style of chapters numbering with *.cls and *.sty files

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I have downloaded an archive with inside a *.cls and *.sty file. I want to get a similar result like the style of the chapter numbering below. Is it a simple image the style on the number in this screenshot, or should i look inside the files that i have mentioned, before to understand how it has been generated?

[image]

**Edit 1**: The class that i am currently using is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,oneside]{book}
```

Comment: Yesterday my car did not start. It is a blue car. Can you tell me why it did not start? ;-)

Comment: If they're short .cls and .sty files, you can try your luck and see if you can figure out how it was done.  Longer files can be tough to understand.  But it would be easier to forget the .cls and .sty files, and just go to "I'd like to format my document like so".  Google how to adjust the section titles (titling package, IIRC), and then come to us with any questions you may still have.

Comment: @Teepeemm The `titling` package is for customizing the `\title` command. For chapter and section headings use `titlesec`.  See [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726)

Comment: @Teepeemm is what i am doing right now but wanted to have a direction in what type of command shoul i look to reproduce such style. The *.sty file is short and i will post it tomorrow if it’s not subjected to copyright.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer are you suggesting that i should provide more information before i can get an answer :) ?

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks i will start from that command, do you think i should look in the *.sty file to understand how they do it? because i have also noticed that the tex file uses a customizable document class.

Comment: Chances are,  both cls and sty files,  are bad.

Comment: @decimal: Exactly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Something similar can be achieved by redefining the standard definition for the chapterhead.

[image: decimalChapterhead]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,blindtext}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  \vspace*{20pt}%
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedleft \normalfont
    \ifnum \value{secnumdepth} >-1
      \if@mainmatter
        {\fontsize{56pt}{0pt}\color{red!50!black}\bfseries\thechapter
        \par}\nobreak
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40pt
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Wombat and Alpaca}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Could i change separetely, with the redefinition of the *\makechapterhead* command(of the **book** class) the font or size of the chapter number from that of his title? With the *\chapterfont* command of the **secsty** package it change both as stated in the documentation.

Comment: @decimal The size is different in the example given. Try `140pt` instead of just `56pt`.

Comment: Yes, didn't noticed that because i am a beginner with commands. I though it was much easier to get this type of customization but obviously i need to learn more about this things. For those of you who are interested, here there are good examples of chapter styling with the **memoir** class https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf. Because the **memoir** class it's based on the **book** class i will try to switch to it for my thesis hoping it doesn't change a lot of what i did.

Comment: @decimal `memoir` is an alternative to a standard class, not based on it. The redefinition from above won't work with memoir. Here is what i was talking about earlier: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423045/37907

Comment: yes, the redefinition of the commands(that didn't exist) that you wrote below, should work if i use the **memoir** class.

Comment: Have you thought about reading an introduction to LaTeX? Your question was completely based on strange assumptions, and honestly, i think it needs to be improved.

Comment: No, nothing i posted today will work properly with `memoir`.

Comment: Yes i though about getting more knowledge on LaTeX. I am currently a bit busy with other things but i have any kind of manual(except those of chapters style) in my list to read. Thanks again for your time and unfortunately i can't up vote your answer.