# Changing chapter titles in Masters-Doctoral-thesis template

Tags: formatting, chapters, templates

I'm using [MastersDoctoralThesis template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) to write my thesis. By default it gives chapters as below:

## 1 Introduction

I  want a title similar to below (center aligned, CAPITALIZED, and chapter number in roman numerals)

### Chapter I

### INTRODUCTION

Comment: ***DO NOT MODIFY THIS CLASS!!!***

Comment: @Johannes_B why do u say so ?

Comment: Look at the very top, license and copyright.

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

> If you do not have to use this template, do not use it. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

---

Do not make any changes to the class file. If you do, you must rename it.

Add the following three lines to the preamble to get what you want. There is no need to change the class file. The class was designed to be customizable to the end user. The option `chapterinoneline` is not default and needs to be commented out.

```
\renewcommand{\chapteralign}{\centering}
\renewcommand{\chapterfont}{\Huge\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
```

and in the document body use

```
 \chapter{{Wombat}}
```

(note the extra craces).

[image: anupMdt]

---

Alternatively, one could use at a later point

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\mdtChapapp}{}{}
\renewcommand{\chapteralign}{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand{\chapterfont}{\color{black}\huge}
\renewcommand{\chapterinbetweenskip}{}{\vspace*{0pt}}
\renewcommand{\chapterprefixfont}{\fontsize{56pt}{0pt}\selectfont\color{mdtRed}}

\chapter{Alpaca}
```

to get the following result:

[image: anupMdtAlt]

Disclaimer: Only with the next update.

Comment: thank you! it works .. but there are a liitle more concerns.1. Single set of braces worked as well. 2. chapter numbers are now I, II, III but when using \section{First section} in fourth chapter, it gives: 
IV.1 First section
i.e section numbering also changed partially into roman (both in TOC and main body)
PS : I need to keep section numbering

Comment: @anupdhungana Please edit the question.

Comment: Of course it changes. The sections inherit the style of the chapters. It is a matter of consistency.

Comment: You can change the section numbering similar to the chapter numbering. `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}`

Comment: that works very well. one more question just for clarification: why is double braces required ? it worked in single {} in my case.

Comment: @anupdhungana I need it on my machine. Didn't look closer into it. The extra pair of braces makes sure that the whole title is converted to all caps.

Comment: oh yeah ! I just checked into it. Double braces only convert to upper caps. However, even when using double braces, the toc didnot show all caps (just for your info, i am good with the solution you provided). thanks

Comment: @anupdhungana  You never specified the toc should be uppercased as well. In that case, the most simple solution is to input the title uppercased: `\chapter{WOMBAT}`